# In a 2D game with an isometric camera (like Bastion) do I need to create a new animation for every angle the player is facing?

Tags: 2d, animation, isometric

For different actions like jumping, attacking, moving etc,  do I need to make new animations for every angle I am doing the action? Or is there a way to somehow run around that requirement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always just use 3d models instead of 2d art (3d models don't neccessarily mean a 3d game). Apart from that, not much. You could mirror half of the sprites, but that may interfere with the lighting a bit.

Comment: Mirrorring the sprites may not be advisable if the character isn't exactly symmetrical (and generally speaking, a good (organic) character design should never be fully symmetric). Especially animations such as attacks are hardly ever symmetrical.